# Error in R java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: r, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I want to use subspace clustering algorithm of the package subspace. When I run the dataset provided by R and the package as example my program works correctly.

But once I am running the code with my dataset I getting an error. The size of my data is 57 MB. I am running this code in Rstudio version 1.0.153.

```
library("R.matlab")
dataOrg <- readMat ("forAfrooz-8-17.mat")
data<-allASD.dynamicRoiCompsRho <- (dataOrg)[[37]]
dim(allASD.dynamicRoiCompsRho)
options(java.parameters = "-Xmx4G")
library("rJava")
library("subspace")
library("RWekajars")
debug(FIRES)
cl2<-FIRES(data)
```

I try to increase the size of the heap space but I am still getting the following  error when I try to debug my code:

```
Error in rJava::.jcall("JavaObjectFromDataConverter", returnSig = "[[D",  : 
  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

How can I deal with this error ? Is there an other way to increase my heap space ?

Answer (score -1):

use "options(java.parameters = "-Xmx8000m")" on the top of your script.